# Can't access variable value outside function [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, exif-js

I'm having a problem with my javascript code.

It basically consists of a script that accesses the exif of a photo and then shows it on an HTML page, more specifically the latitude and longitude of it.

The idea is to then use both the latitude and longitude on a Google maps iframe to then show the location that photo was taken. But that's later as this is only a test page I'm using to ecperiment the workings of it.

The thing is that before using the latitude and longitude, it has to be converted into a format recognised by that same iframe:

EX: the output of "latitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitude")" would be:

41,23.0692,0

and it needs to be something like this:

41.38448666666667

I have a function that does just that and it works if i do something like this:

```
var toDecimal = function (number) {
  var d = Math.floor(number[0]);
  var m = Math.floor(number[1]);
  var s = ((number[1]%1)*60);

  var dms = d+(m/60)+(s/3600);

  return dms

};

var latitude_teste="41,23.0692,0";
var latitude_array = latitude_teste.split(',');
var latitude_final = toDecimal(latitude_array);
var local_lat_final = document.getElementById("local_lat_final");
local_lat_final.innerHTML = `${latitude_final}`;
```

But if I try to use this method above like this (latitude being the variable from the function getExif()):

```
var latitude_teste=latitude;
var latitude_array = latitude_teste.split(',');
var latitude_final = toDecimal(latitude_array);
var local_lat_final = document.getElementById("local_lat_final");
local_lat_final.innerHTML = `${latitude_final}`;
```

It won't show any value at all for latitude...

Why am I having this problem? Is it some syntax mistake?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>EXIF</title>
    <style>
        img{
            width: 500px;
            max-height: auto;
        }   
    </style>    
</head>

<body>

    <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4867/30883801817_bf122bc498_o.jpg" id="img1" />


    <h1>Latitude Exif</h1>
    <p id="local_lat"></p>

    <h1>Longitude Exif</h1>
    <p id="local_lon"></p>

    <h1>Latitude Final</h1>
    <p id="local_lat_final"></p>

    <h1>Longitude Final</h1>
    <p id="local_lon_final"></p>

    <script src="exif.js"></script>

    <script>

        window.onload=getExif;


        function getExif() {
            var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
            EXIF.getData(img1, function() {

            latitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitude");
            var longitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLongitude");  

            var local_lat = document.getElementById("local_lat");
            var local_lon = document.getElementById("local_lon");

            local_lat.innerHTML = `${latitude}`;
            local_lon.innerHTML = `${longitude}`;
            });


        }

        /*função para converter latitude e longitude do exif.js 
        em graus decimais, legíveis pelo google maps*/

        var toDecimal = function (number) {


            var d = Math.floor(number[0]);
            var m = Math.floor(number[1]);
            var s = ((number[1]%1)*60);

            var dms= d+(m/60)+(s/3600);

            return dms

        };

        var latitude_teste="41,23.0692,0";
        var latitude_array = latitude_teste.split(',');
        var latitude_final = toDecimal(latitude_array);
        var local_lat_final = document.getElementById("local_lat_final");
        local_lat_final.innerHTML = `${latitude_final}`;

        /*THIS PIECE OF CODE BELOW WON'T WORK if used to replace the one above*/


        /*
        var latitude_teste=latitude;
        var latitude_array = latitude_teste.split(',');
        var latitude_final = toDecimal(latitude_array);
        var local_lat_final = document.getElementById("local_lat_final");
        local_lat_final.innerHTML = `${latitude_final}`;

        */

        var longitude_teste="2,6.4013,0";
        var longitude_array = longitude_teste.split(',');
        var longitude_final = toDecimal(longitude_array);
        var local_lon_final = document.getElementById("local_lon_final");
        local_lon_final.innerHTML = `${longitude_final}`;


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is most likely *timing*. ***When*** does `latitude` become available…?

Comment: Supposedly on window.onload=getExif;

Comment: Exactly, `getExif` will be executed *sometime later* (on window load), yet your code expects the variable to be there immediately. Further, even `EXIF.getData` may be executing asynchronously.

Comment: What should I do then? (adding to some needed reading I guess). Is there a way to implement some kind of delay for the code to only expect the variable after it has become available?

Comment: @deceze while your diagnostic is correct (timing issue), I wouldn't close this as a dup of 14220321 - the solution here is quite simply to move the top-level code (the "non working" part) whithin `getExif()` so it's executed at the right time, no need to bother with async/await etc and we ALREADY have the "callback" (getExif, to name it).

Comment: @bruno Well that is also widely discussed there, probably most succinctly in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23819901/476.

Comment: @RafaelLopes just move your "code that doesn't work" within the callback you pass to `EXIF.getData` (and remove the code used to parse 'latitude' and 'longitude', thos are already arrays), cf https://gist.github.com/BrunoDesthuilliers/de5ee721437d50513d11493c85d07957

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Done that and it is indeed working now! Thanks very much!

Comment: @RafaelLopes do you now understand why it didn't work and why/how my gist solved the problem ? (If not, take time to understand it, else you will get similar problems again and again and again).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I did understand the sense of it being a question of timing between when the values are available and when they are requested. The technical part of it will require time to refine as I'm doing this project a bit on a "self-learning" way. This kind of experience with errors/mistakes is with no doubt, enriching to my knowledge.

This bit of code is also only a test as I'll need to convert it to work, not with an image already loaded on the website but with an image the user selects using <input type="file" ... many doubts/problems are sure to come... :/

Comment: @RafaelLopes, you should not update your question with code you get from solutions. It makes it very confusing. StackOverflow is intended to have answers in the answer section, not in the question area.

Comment: @trincot fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

The `latitude` you get from `EXIF.getTag()` is already an array. It is only because you output it as a string that you see a comma-separated string, but it really is an array.

So in your code you shouldn't do the `split()`:

```
var latitude_teste=latitude;
var latitude_array = latitude_teste.split(',');
var latitude_final = toDecimal(latitude_array);
```

Instead just do:

```
var latitude_final = toDecimal(latitude);
```

Addendum: you should place this code in the callback you have to `EXIF.getTag()`. That you tried to access the `latitude` and `longitude` *outside* of it is the reason for the duplicate/closure.

Comment: I tried this and it still won't show any value on the page... weird. Also, if I use "typeof" for latitude it does indeed say it is a string.

Comment: @trincot your observation is technically correct (and the code will not work without this fix), but that's not the root cause either - the first problem is that this code should be within  the `EXIF.getData`'s callback.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, as far as I can see in the code the OP has posted at the end of his question, the code *is* correctly put within the callback, albeit his code is not indented properly.

Comment: @trincot this code is the fixed version I posted as a gist, not the original non-working code ;-)

Comment: Oh I see, the OP has incrementally updated their question which now even includes this fix. My, my, this is confusing :-)

Comment: @trincot I'm sorry for the confusion created by my last edit. Was not intentional and it's fixed now :)